# Moving from DOM-manipulation to object-oriented Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently use javascript in a very basic way to manipulate the DOM. This isn't very DRY - for each "widget" I create, I have to copy and paste a chunk of code. I'm anticipating that maintaining this code is going to be a chore!

I'd rather create an object for each "widget", and then I can edit the 'class' of the widget when I want to change all the widgets of that type.

Here for example is a dropdown menu widget (a button), with two input fields (minimum and maximum) in the menu. Changing the inputs updates the title on the button.

Is it possible to build this behaviour into a javascript object?

```
// Year

var year_button  = $("#year-dropdown");
var year_minimum = $("#year-minimum");
var year_maximum = $("#year-maximum");

year_minimum.keyup( update_year )
year_maximum.keyup( update_year )

function update_year(){
  update_year_button();
  update_year_in_description();
}

function update_year_button(){
  year_button.html( get_year_title() )
}

function get_year_title(){
  var min = year_minimum.val();
  var max = year_maximum.val();
  if(min == "" && max == ""){
    return "YEAR"
  } else if(max == "") {
    return "YEAR: " + min
  } else {
    return "YEARS: " + min + " - " + max
  }
}

// Height

var height_button  = $("#height-dropdown");
var height_minimum = $("#height-minimum");
var height_maximum = $("#height-maximum");

height_minimum.keyup( update_height )
height_maximum.keyup( update_height )

function update_height(){
  update_height_button();
}

function update_height_button(){
  height_button.html( get_height_title() )
}


function get_height_title(){
  var min = height_minimum.val();
  var max = height_maximum.val();
  var unit = get_unit();
  if(min == "" && max == ""){
    return "HEIGHT"
  } else if(max == "") {
    return "HEIGHT: " + min + " " + unit;
  } else {
    return "HEIGHT: " + min + " - " + max + " " + unit;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can have a look at [jQuery Plugins](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/). This may help you

Comment: Since you want to build reusable components, you may like [react js](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html)

Comment: Is it possible with normal JS objects, and .prototype objects?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this. Arguably the `new` syntax is a better fit for this. But here's a prototypial version:

```
var widget_thing = {
  elements: {
    dropdown: false,
    minimum: false,
    maximum: false
  },

  init: function () {
    var self = this
    self.button  = $(self.elements.dropdown)
    self.minimum = $(self.elements.minimum)
    self.maximum = $(self.elements.maximum)
    self.minimum.keyup( update_elem )
    self.maximum.keyup( update_elem )
  },

  update_elem: function () {
    var self = this
    self.update_button()
    self.update_in_description()
  },

  update_button: function () {
    var self = this
    self.button.html( self.get_title() )
  },

  update_in_description: function () {

  },

  get_title: function () {
    console.log('Please specify a get_title function')
  }
}
```

Now that you have this object, you can do this:

```
year_widget_thing = Object.create(widget_thing)
year_widget_thing.elements.year_button  = '#year-dropdown'
year_widget_thing.elements.year_minimum = '#year-minimum'
year_widget_thing.elements.year_maximum = '#year-maximum'
year_widget_thing.get_title = function () {
  var self = this
  var min = self.minimum.val()
  var max = self.maximum.val()
  var unit = get_unit()
  if(min == "" && max == ""){
    return "YEAR"
  } else if(max == "") {
    return "YEAR: " + min + " " + unit
  } else {
    return "YEARS: " + min + " - " + max + " " + unit
  }
}

year_widget_thing.init()
```

EDIT: I didn't actually test this, so it could contain small errors.

Comment: This is the perfect introduction to OO javascript, thank you so much. Will test this out when I can, and mark you as correct if it works!